# aspx site behaves different on the webserver...but why?

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, css

I designed a simple site with some css and jquery. All the css is in the header using  and the javascript files are in a folder called Scripts and referenced in my site like below. Everything is beautiful locally, but on the server some objects such as a couple of my divs are out of their original positions, and my dropdown menus that use jquery don't work properly but they do work somewhat (like they slide down or fade).

I have made identical folder structure in root on the web server. I am using .NET 3.5 and the server does support it.

Do you guys think it can be a path issue for my scripts? 
What could cause the css to move divs out of position? 
Does css or jquery behave differently on different servers?

```
  <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.easing.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks a bunch

Comment: You should include *just* the minified version in production, not the non-minified or `-vsdoc`, also be sure to include only one version of jQuery :)  All plugins should be included after jQuery, and one last thing, the color plugin isn't needed if you're including jQuery UI.  It would look like this overall: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YafaA/

Comment: thanks Nick, I don't think script paths are my problem any more, because the jquery is working (there's fading, sliding etc but out of order). It's just not working properly. My divs are misaligned which is a css issue...that only happens on production server. I have no idea why.

Comment: Please try changing the DOCTYPE of your master page, or your page, as sometimes it decides rendering behaviours.

Comment: I'm a bit new, how should I change DOCTYPE or to what? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wyatt Barnett's suggestion is where I would start. Clear your cache, look in Firebug's Net console and watch for any pages coming in 404.

If that fails, concentrate on finding the differences between the source code / support files on your production and development servers. Get a diff tool (I'm on a Mac and I use FileMerge, but there are heaps of very good, free diff tools available for every platform). Save the page source of your production and development pages (ignore what the server is supposed to be building, look at what the browser is actually getting instead). Pay close attention to any CSS differences there might be, or any extraneous elements that may be getting injected into the document in your production environment.

Lastly, change your development pages so that they point directly at your JS files on your production environment. If you accidentally changed one of these files, or if they got saved at different versions, it would account for the problems you're seeing.

If the page source code is identical and the JS files are identical and there are no issues with loading the files, my next guess is gremlins. They get into everything.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding up ~ sign before paths, example:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: I agree with this as this happened to my team about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: hmmm...I tried this but now my jquery is not even working. Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: well I added the scripts as o6tech described and I'm back to the same issue...my divs are misaligned and my jquery does things out of order.

Answer (score 1):

ScriptManager is your friend

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.2.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.color.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: That takes me back to my current issue...my divs are out of place and my jquery is buggy.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd do is fire up a HTTP debugger and see what scripts or stylesheets are missing.

Second thing I'd do is fire up firebug and see what script and stylesheet errors I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, it may not be a script issue at all it may be a css issue.  It would cause things to appear differently on your page, yet have some of your JavaScript code work.  Have you checked to make sure your including your style sheets correctly??

Comment: My style is included in the header, no css files. Since everything works locally I'm not sure what could be different on the server.
Thanks!